# AngularJs/CSS: Table width dynamic rows and columns in a horizontal layout

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want following layout:

```
Date       2015-10-23     2015-10-21     2015-11-21
User1      10 min         20 min         30 min
User2      20 min         05 min         03 min
User3      03 min         93 min         10 min
Notes      Some note      Some other     Nothing to note
           with new line  note
Status     Done           Interrupted    Ongoing
```

The first column is a header column, the following columns are generated by angular.
The UserX rows are generated dynamically as well.
For me it looks like a "flipped" table, where the columns are more like rows. I wan't that it looks like a table (keeping the height of the cells to the row, and the width to the column).
What would be the best approach here? Is it possible with html table+CSS?
My model looks like:

```
 [
    {
        date: '2015-10-23',
        notes: 'some note',
        status: 'status',
        participants: [
             {
                  name: 'User1',
                  duration: '1 minute'
             },
             {
                  name: 'User2',
                  duration: '9 minute'
             }
        ]
 ]
```

I tried to compose the table as a normal table, that is with `Date, User1, User2...` as first row, and then "flip" the table with following css:

```
tr { display: block; float: left; }
th, td { display: block;  }
```

But this way the height of the cells wasn't preceived, a multi-line note "broke" the table.

https://jsfiddle.net/alecc/cvf5vp8p/7/

I tried in the angular controller to compose the data in such a way how it's displayed, but I don't like this approach either.

https://jsfiddle.net/alecc/gzc13fh9/2/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a 'th' in each 'tr':

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Datum</th>
    <td ng-repeat='datum in datums'>{{datum}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat='name in teilnehmerListe'>
    <th >{{name}}</th>
    <td ng-repeat="attr in name">{{attr}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sonstige Teilnehmer?</th>
    <td ng-repeat='sonstige in sonstiges'>{{sonstige}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Bemerkungen</th>
    <td ng-repeat='bemerkungen in bemerkungens'>{{bemerkungen}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

PS: for style you should use the `<td> colspan` attribute.

Comment: That doesn't sound performant, for each object we do a foreach at least 5 times and one additional time for each additional participant.

Comment: Well, maybe you could group your data to improve the performance. Forget the 'classic' table pattern for now.

Anything else would be a hack and you will have problems in crossbrowser styling, keep in mind that angular ng-repeat works better if you use a key attribute.

Comment: So my second approach in preparing the data in such way that I can display it with a normal table sounds like a way to go?

Comment: PS: I really don't see actually why the classic table solution would be better, for your model I would iterate through the keys of the object and create a table row for each key.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you're after some sort of fixed table layout.

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th, td {   
width: 125px;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/L7hghdus/)